# In an international collaboration, what can be used for a shared meetings log or electronic labbook?

Tags: collaboration, productivity, tools, note-taking, lab-meeting

I started to have more and more international collaborations recently resulting in more and more (video conference) meetings. While in some meetings, there is one guys summing up the result of the meeting and send it around to everybody via email, I do not think this is the optimal way as sometimes people share references or results and then they send it again via email to everybody.

My questions now is if you have any recommendations on what to use for a shared meetings log or a shared electronic notebook, where everybody can contribute to? Requirements would be

- ability to type formulas
- insert images
- insert link
- accessible for editing by everybody (maybe after some kind of registration)

Comment: Git repository managers (e.g. GitLab or GitHub) seem to meet your requirements. You can keep your logs either in a project's wiki page or in a markdown file (e.g. your project's readme).

Comment: @101010111100 hm, indeed, GitLab offers the possibility to manage user-restricted access (yes, GitHub does that, too, but it requires a premium account, if I am not wrong). One could also use GitLab to share pdfs (papers/references). I have never used a wiki page on one of those platforms, but I will definitely have a look into it!

Comment: This isn't really academia-specific; you can use basically any platform for writing and editing shared documents. Google Docs, whatever Microsoft's online office offering is, ShareLaTeX or Overleaf (if you prefer LaTeX), etc.

Comment: @ff524 The Microsoft online office offering is OneNote, and while it's a part of the office suite it's actually free. Quite handy for the people that don't want to pay, and for the vast majority of people in academia that have it already installed.

Comment: @VonBeche Actually I was referring to office.com which AFAIK has much more than just OneNote (all free).

Comment: @VonBeche Microsoft products are somewhat problematic: most of us (actually the vast majority) work on Linux at our institute. But, true, the web-option mentioned by user ff524 might be an option